# OSGI two dependency chain issue when upgrading cxf jars

Tags: osgi, cxf

I got the following error in felix.log after adding javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api-1.4.0.jar in osgi/custo directory, how to understand the error message and what could be the possible fix?

```
WARN - 2022-10-17 14:36:22,821 - FelixDispatchQueue - Could not start bundle: file:custo/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.4.8.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws [org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws [231](R 231.0)] because it is exposed to package 'javax.xml.soap' from resources javax.xml.soap-api [javax.xml.soap-api [144](R 144.0)] and org.apache.felix.framework [org.apache.felix.framework [0](R 0)] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws [org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws [231](R 231.0)]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.soap)(version>=1.4.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.xml.soap
  javax.xml.soap-api [javax.xml.soap-api [144](R 144.0)]

Chain 2:
  org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws [org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws [231](R 231.0)]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.ws.handler.soap)(version>=0.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.xml.ws.handler.soap; uses:=javax.xml.soap
    export: osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.soap
  org.apache.felix.framework [org.apache.felix.framework [0](R 0)] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws [231](R 231.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.ws.handler.soap)(version>=0.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4398)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2308)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:1006)
        at com.alcatel.as.service.bundleinstaller.impl.BundleInstallerImpl$DeployedBundle.start(BundleInstallerImpl.java:935)
        at com.alcatel.as.service.bundleinstaller.impl.BundleInstallerImpl.startBundles(BundleInstallerImpl.java:624)
        at com.alcatel.as.service.bundleinstaller.impl.BundleInstallerImpl.finishInitialisation(BundleInstallerImpl.java:260)
        at com.alcatel.as.service.bundleinstaller.impl.BundleInstallerImpl.frameworkEvent(BundleInstallerImpl.java:244)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.invokeFrameworkListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:881)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:830)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.run(EventDispatcher.java:1147)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.access$000(EventDispatcher.java:54)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher$1.run(EventDispatcher.java:102)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

if I don't install javax.xml.soap-api-1.4.0.jar, I will get the following exception with cxf 3.4.8 package:

```
WARN - 2022-10-19 07:48:04,272 - FelixDispatchQueue - Could not start bundle: file:custo/cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.4.8.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-simple [25](R 25.0): missing requirement [org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-simple [25](R 25.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor)(version>=3.4.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-soap [112](R 112.0): missing requirement [org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-soap [112](R 112.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.soap)(version>=1.4.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-simple [25](R 25.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor)(version>=3.4.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4398)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2308)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:1006)
        at com.alcatel.as.service.bundleinstaller.impl.BundleInstallerImpl$DeployedBundle.start(BundleInstallerImpl.java:935)
        at com.alcatel.as.service.bundleinstaller.impl.BundleInstallerImpl.startBundles(BundleInstallerImpl.java:624)
        at com.alcatel.as.service.bundleinstaller.impl.BundleInstallerImpl.finishInitialisation(BundleInstallerImpl.java:260)
        at com.alcatel.as.service.bundleinstaller.impl.BundleInstallerImpl.frameworkEvent(BundleInstallerImpl.java:244)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.invokeFrameworkListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:881)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:830)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.run(EventDispatcher.java:1147)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.access$000(EventDispatcher.java:54)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher$1.run(EventDispatcher.java:102)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
WARN - 2022-10-19 07:48:04,881 - FelixDispatchQueue - Could not start bundle: file:custo/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.4.8.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws [84](R 84.0): missing requirement [org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws [84](R 84.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.soap)(version>=1.4.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws [84](R 84.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.soap)(version>=1.4.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4398)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2308)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:1006)
        at com.alcatel.as.service.bundleinstaller.impl.BundleInstallerImpl$DeployedBundle.start(BundleInstallerImpl.java:935)
        at com.alcatel.as.service.bundleinstaller.impl.BundleInstallerImpl.startBundles(BundleInstallerImpl.java:624)
        at com.alcatel.as.service.bundleinstaller.impl.BundleInstallerImpl.finishInitialisation(BundleInstallerImpl.java:260)
        at com.alcatel.as.service.bundleinstaller.impl.BundleInstallerImpl.frameworkEvent(BundleInstallerImpl.java:244)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.invokeFrameworkListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:881)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:830)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.run(EventDispatcher.java:1147)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.access$000(EventDispatcher.java:54)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher$1.run(EventDispatcher.java:102)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: You've installed `javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api-1.4.0.jar`, but you don't have to do it - the packages are exported by _system bundle_.

Comment: I posted the exception in the description if I didn't install the soap-api-1.4.0.jar.

Comment: What is the version of `javax.xml.soap` exported by system bundle? In Karaf, you can set it in `jre.properties`. If you install `javax.xml.soap-api-1.4.0.jar` separately, you can remove the export of the problematic package from system bundle.